# how to get the information from a http head in android

Tags: android, json, http-headers

i've been given the task to send a POST message to the server giving it a JSON encoded message. The server would then send back a responce in a custom HTTP header field “X-SubmissionResponse”

so far i can successfully connect to the server (i know this because i get the responce code 202)

but i am having a lot of difficulty in getting the information from the responce, below is the code that i am currently using.

```
Error content not available
```

This code ends up returning null, Can anyone see what i am missing here?

This is the code above the if statement ^

```
    Error content not available
```

Comment: why server is sending response in such format? And give the detail here for the response format

Comment: This is all the information that i have been given : "POST requests to the server - 
Submitting a solution to the server is done by a POST message. The solution should be json-encoded, in the body of the request, as shown in the appendix. The result of the submission will be contained in the custom HTTP header field “X-SubmissionResponse”, and may be “CORRECT”,”WRONG” or “INVALID”."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Header name = response.getFirstHeader("X-SubmissionResponse");
String whatsInhere = "";
if (name != null)
  whatsInhere = name.getValue();
```

Try using the correct methods of the Class Header.
See http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/Header.html

Comment: but the problem is it is returning null, it should be giving me a responce

Comment: If you try "Header[] getAllHeaders()", instead of getFirstHeader, are any headers returned?

Comment: ok ive tried that and it gives an array of 13 however none of the bufferedHeaders have "X-SubmissionResponse" as the name, so im assuming that there is a problem with my supervisors server in that case.

Comment: Actually bufferedHeader 4 contains what i need, its just named different to what i was told to use.

Answer (score 1):

```
HttpHead head = new HttpHead();
```

creates a new HEAD request, empty, that does not do anything in itself.

You want the header from the response to your request. Get it by simply:

```
Header name = response.getFirstHeader("X-SubmissionResponse");
```

Comment: for some reason your code is also returning null to the name variable